# change sender address when sending mail through gmail in c#

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail, networkcredentials

I have used the following code to send mail from my web application using a gmail account. My question is, can i change the sender address to another address other than original sender(gmail) address?
My code is as follows:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sample@gmail.com", "*******");
```

Whatever i do is useless as i always receive mail from `sample@gmail.com`. Is it possible to change it?

I have changed to 
    `mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("sample@yahoo.com");` but i received the mail with the from address `sample@gmail.com` and not from the new "From" address. I think gmail smtp overwrites the from address with the original credential.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Gmail doesn't allow you to change the FROM to something different than your gmail account.

It doesn't matter what you use, they over-write it, before they relay it on. This prevent spamming/spoofing.

Comment: Not true, see my comment below. It is possible, as long as you have the other account added as an alias.

Comment: This is not the correct answer, I implemented philip and Simon_Weaver's answers together today and was able to successfully send email from a G Suite alias using the account's main login details (which are different from the alias).

Answer (score 41):

This is the solution:

1. use the codes above to set mail.From = new MailAddress(address, display name)
2. in Gmail, go to Mail Settings >> Accounts and Import.
3. Add the email account you will use as sender in "Send Mail As". (tick as Alias)

This works for me

Comment: Much better answer. It is possible to change the From in Gmail.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a much better answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes just use the [From](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.from.aspx) property of the [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx)

eg.

```
mail.From = "newemail@email.com";
```

**EDIT**: Also, see this post for more detailed info on how to emails via gmail in C#

[Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

**EDIT:** Although this works for mail in general, it appears this won't work for gmail as google overwrite it before its sent (see @Dave wanta's answer)

Comment: While you're right in general, when specifically sending mail through Google SMTP servers the "From:" property is overwritten.

Comment: This is not true, you CAN use a different from address using Google SMTP. Just make sure it is an alias (as w69rdy points out) and that you follow the RFC 2822 specification (my mistake was having a space between the email and name brackets, it should be test@test.com<Test User>). The sender address will NOT be changed by Google, but you can influence this because it will use the account marked as default in your gmail settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a limited number of senders you can do as @philip suggested. For instance you may have `customerservice@example.com`, `simon@example.com` and `philip@example.com` or even `alias@example.com`. As long as they are approved senders on the actual `gmail.com` website you can send from them.

[Gmail.com : Sending mail from a different address](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370)

If you are expecting to send from an arbitrary user (such as a customer service form on a website where the user enters their email and you don't want them emailing you directly) about the best you can do is this :

```
        msg.ReplyToList.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email, friendlyName));
```

If you're in a controlled environment this works great, but please note that I've seen some email clients send to the from address even when reply-to is specified (I don't know which).

Answer (score 1):

Check #56 and #58. They might be relevant to what you want to do
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=172