# Setting from email on phpmailer

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send emails.  Works great, except the email's From Address shows up as `Me! [myuser@gmail.com]` instead of `Me! [myemail@comcast.net]`.  How do I set the email's From email address?

```
<?php
    require_once ('class.phpmailer.php');
    $email='myemail@comcast.net';


    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP

    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port       = 587;    //Maybe 465 instead? SSL only?
    $mail->Username   = "myusername";
    $mail->Password   = "mypassword";


    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = 'Me!';
    $mail->addAddress($email, 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo($email, 'Information');
    $mail->addCC($email);
    $mail->addBCC($email);

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }

    echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Comment: Can you show us received email source header code? And describe what part troubles you there.

Comment: Unless something has changed fairly recently, the unchangeable 'from' address is intentional - it prevents spoofing: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871577/change-sender-address-when-sending-mail-through-gmail-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871577/change-sender-address-when-sending-mail-through-gmail-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @KristenJukowski.  I am sure you are correct.

Comment: @user1032531 you're not completely out of luck if the 'from' address doesn't need to change and you have control over the associated email account. You can still set that email (myemail@comcast.net) up as a sender from within your gmail account; once you've taken care of that, your code above should work as intended!

Comment: @KristenJukowski.  I will try your solution when I get a chance.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that Kristen is right in the comments, however you could try editing the class.phpmailer.php file and changing the settings there.

```
// The From email address for the message.
// @type string

   public $From = 'root@localhost';

// The From name of the message.
// @type string

   public $FromName = 'Root User';

// The Sender email (Return-Path) of the message.
// If not empty, will be sent via -f to sendmail or as 'MAIL FROM' in smtp mode.
// @type string

    public $Sender = '';
```