# Django send email where smtp auth is different then from_email

Tags: django, email, smtp-auth

I have set up the django smtp backend to use gmail smtp.
and it sends email perfectly, But there is one problem.

The authentication I use for gmail smtp is different then the from_email, still when I receive an email I see the from email id as the smtp auth email.

example:
my settings are as follow:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER= 'something@somedomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD= 'password_for_something_at_gmail_com'
```

and to send an email I did

```
send_mail(subject=subject, message="test", from_email="other@mydomain.com",
recipient_list=to, fail_silently=False)
```

this works but the received email does not show

```
from : other@mydomain.com
```

it shows

```
from: something@somedomain.com
```

How do I make sure it shows `other@mydomain.com`.

NOTE: `somedomain.com` is connected with google apps and `mydomain.com` 
is alias with it 
and `other@mydomain.com` is just an fwd email id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail [doesn't allow you to change the From address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871577/change-sender-address-when-sending-mail-through-gmail-in-c-sharp) [when sending email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332510/how-to-change-from-address-when-using-gmail-smtp-server) [through its servers](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

You can override From header with below email sending code.

from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

EmailMessage(subject, message, "<"+str(from_email)+">", recipient_list)

Note: Actually it will send email from the email id which you configured in settings.py file but From header will show from_email address

Comment: But as Christian points out, this doesn't work for smtp.gmail.com