# When sending an email through my Rails app using ActionMailer I get the email from myself despite of specifying the 'from:' argument

Tags: railsapps, learn-ruby-on-rails

I am following the [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) book from the RailsApps project.  On Chapter 23 we add the send mail functionality to the app.  Everything seems to be working fine expect that the email I receive comes from my own e-mail (regardless of the email I type in the contact form).

It is strange because in the server log, the "sender" seems to be ok.  However when I check my e-mail online (gmail) it appears as if I was both the sender and the recipient.

Here is the code from the server log:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for ::1 at 2015-03-02 14:06:09 -0500
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"XRDoCx9oADWIWAKWRGgmQSaWaN0HLa8JywAsaNS/4N1YPlME9Z2gtEk6hQikwwrLWPDOtNoL9NfABUO2PGOYwQ==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"John Doe", "email"=>"j.doe@jd.com", "content"=>"Hello world!"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}

WARNING: GoogleDriveV0.login is deprecated and will be removed in the next version. Use GoogleDriveV0.login_with_oauth instead.

DEPRECATION WARNING: `#deliver` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5. Use `#deliver_now` to deliver immediately or `#deliver_later` to deliver through Active Job. (called from create at /Users/SergioRodriguez/workspace/learn-rails/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:17)
Rendered user_mailer/contact_email.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered user_mailer/contact_email.text.erb (0.1ms)

UserMailer#contact_email: processed outbound mail in 37.5ms

Sent mail to my.email@gmail.com (2314.6ms)
Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2015 14:08:03 -0500
From: j.doe@jd.com
To: my.email@gmail.com
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer: [change sender address when sending mail through gmail in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871577/change-sender-address-when-sending-mail-through-gmail-in-c-sharp)

> Gmail doesn't allow you to change the FROM to something different than
>   your gmail account.
>
> It doesn't matter what you use, they over-write it, before they relay
>   it on. This prevent spamming/spoofing.