# Sending mail from website in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web

I coded a website contact form with mail send and after dozens of research cannot find an answer hoping stackoverflow users can help.

The aspx.cs file signs into the specified gmail configuration to send the email HOWEVER is there a way to set the SENDER as what the user inputs in the email textbox, so instead of recieving the email from myself so when clicking "Reply" on the mailbox its not replying to myself? If that makes sense?

So the sender is not me but the sender is what the user inputs in the mail box and I receive the email FROM the input value rather than myself

Comment: Could you post some of your code?  Are you using the MailMessage class?

Comment: Yes using system.net.mail and the mailmessage class, tried setting the "from" as the textbox id but still no luck

Comment: Is this similar to what you're trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871577/change-sender-address-when-sending-mail-through-gmail-in-c-sharp

Comment: Vyrotek - yes similar but gmail overwrites like they said is there a none hassle way of just code to handle it rather than configuring gmail?

Comment: They reason they do it is to prevent abuse and spoofing. I'm under the impression you want to be able to send an email from any address enter into a textbox. Even from ones you don't "own". To send an email you need to send it from/to an email server and in my experience all reputable APIs and services require you to prove ownership of the FROM address.

Comment: Yes, i want to recieve emails FROM what the value of the textbox is entered by the USER on the website

Comment: It's always a good idea to include some code to help paint a clearer picture of what you're asking, what you've tried, and what your specific problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

> This is the solution:
>
> 1. set mail.From = new MailAddress(address, display name)
> 2. in Gmail, go to Mail Settings >> Accounts and Import.
> 3. Add the email account you will use as sender in "Send Mail As". (tick
>      as Alias)

This is the only way gmail will let you specify the from address.

Comment: Hi Parameter. Okay i understand that for the gmail, what about other mail servers such as webhost provided and outlook etc, do they require the same permission of alias OR is this a GMAIL ONLY thing?

Comment: I'd have to imagine you'd have more flexibility with other mail servers, but quick research hasn't led me to any solid answers.  Another possibility is setting the ReplyToList property so that your 'reply to' address isn't pointed to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the From Address requires special configuration/confirmation in Gmail for each From Address (see [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)), or is otherwise prohibited.

You could create a generic gmail address such as `no-reply-yourapp@gmail.com`.  Then use the [ReplyToList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replytolist(v=vs.110).aspx) property to set the default Reply To email address that the user will use for their reply, to the user input email address, as well as an appropriate Display Name for the sender.

Answer (score 0):

So in theory, for flexibilty use different mail service such as web host provided or outlook etc and set the mail.FROM to the value from the textbox and it will be sent from the address the user has typed? Gmail being extra secure causes confusion. Got it. Thanks guys